# Ok to use select in where query?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that contains product sets IDs containing product IDs. Nid is product set ID and second row contains products attached to the set. The reason why 2 tables is that first table contains paid products, second table contains free products. Based on existing products in cart, I  created a query to get results like this:

1 product in cart having ID = 45
result:

| nid | field_prod_in_set_nid | field_additional_set_prod_nid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 67 | 45,45 | 45 |

query: ($items_string is variable containing product IDs)

```
SELECT i.nid, GROUP_CONCAT(i.field_prod_in_set_nid SEPARATOR ',') as set_products, ad.additional 
FROM {content_field_prod_in_set} i      
JOIN (
    SELECT c.nid, GROUP_CONCAT(c.field_additional_set_prod_nid SEPARATOR ',') as additional
    FROM
    {content_field_additional_set_prod} c
    GROUP BY c.nid) ad ON ad.nid = i.nid    
WHERE 
    i.nid IN (SELECT nid FROM {content_field_prod_in_set} WHERE field_prod_in_set_nid IN ($items_string))   
GROUP BY i.nid
```

content_field_prod_in_set

| nid | field_prod_in_set_nid |
| --- | --- |
| 62 | 3 |
| 62 | 3 |
| 64 | 3 |
| 63 | 15 |
| 64 | 25 |
| 62 | 29 |
| 67 | 45 |
| 67 | 45 |

content_field_additional_set_prod

| nid | field_additional_set_prod_nid |
| --- | --- |
| 62 | 46 |
| 62 | 9 |
| 63 | NULL |
| 64 | 46 |
| 67 | 45 |

QUESTION :
Is it possible to write the query without having select in WHERE ? I read that this is not a good practice and it is slow. Thank you.

Comment: "not good practice" is vague and not good advice. SQL statements are typically slow because of their execution plan or serialization.

Comment: MySQL often optimizes `WHERE column IN (SELECT ...)` poorly. You can usually get the same result by joining with the subquery.

Comment: Why do you have `{}` around the table names?

Comment: @Barmar I wok in drupal cms where it used. Not sure if it is necessary.

Comment: The `WHERE i.nid IN (SELECT)` is testing the same table. Why can't you just use `WHERE field_prod_in_set_nid IN ($items_string)` in the main query?

Comment: @Barmar I have tried that already but that way it does not select all the nids for GROUP_CONCAT. for example if $items_string = 3, the result is 62 | 3,3 | .... instead of 62 | 3,3,29...

Comment: I was thinking that `nid` was unique, I didn't check the sample data closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with the subquery instead of using `WHERE IN`.

```
SELECT i.nid, GROUP_CONCAT(i.field_prod_in_set_nid SEPARATOR ',') as set_products, ad.additional 
FROM content_field_prod_in_set i      
JOIN (
    SELECT c.nid, GROUP_CONCAT(c.field_additional_set_prod_nid SEPARATOR ',') as additional
    FROM
    content_field_additional_set_prod c
    GROUP BY c.nid) ad ON ad.nid = i.nid    
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT nid
      FROM content_field_prod_in_set
      WHERE field_prod_in_set_nid IN ($items_string)
     ) i2 ON i2.nid = i.nid
GROUP BY i.nid
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dab58/8)

`SELECT DISTINCT` is needed in the subquery to avoid duplicating the results in the `GROUP_CONCAT()` for each matching `nid`.